# Can multiple apps handle ibeacon events

Tags: android, ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am working on a proof of concept for a community organization involving Ibeacons. I know very little about IOS development.

The basic idea is that the community organization will have an app, and the various entities that we will deploy Ibeacons at my also have an app. is it possible with IOS to set a priority on which apps handle specific beacon events.

So lets say if a user has Business X's app installed and a beacon event from a beacon associated with Business X is installed, then Business X's app will handle the event. Otherwise the Community app will handle the event?

I know in Android you can set a priority for intent handling. I'm not sure if that can be done with Ibeacons in IOS or in Android.

Comment: can you help me how to scan using multiple UUID in android.
I have 10 of them and anyone can be scanned

Answer (score 1):

Beacons, or beacon 'events' don't belong to a specific app. Beacons broadcast an identifier composed of three values - a UUID and major and minor values. These three values can be used by your apps to set up a monitoring region. For each app you can monitor one or more regions (groupings of beacons) that it needs to know about. Multiple apps can monitor the same beacons. Any prioritisation of beacon discovery and ranging events would need to be handled within your individual apps.

For example given these three beacons:

- BeaconA: UUID=DCCABFE0-A25D-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66 Major=293 Minor=1
- BeaconB: UUID=DCCABFE0-A25D-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66 Major=293 Minor=2
- BeaconC: UUID=DCCABFE0-A25D-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66 Major=674 Minor=1

Your Community App could be monitoring all beacons with the UUID DCCABFE0-A25D-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66 (3 beacons). Business X's app may monitor a subset of these by monitoring beacons with the UUID DCCABFE0-A25D-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66 and Major value 293 (2 beacons). In this case if BeaconA was detected by the device iBeacon events would be triggered for both of the apps because BeaconA is within regions monitored by both. However if BeaconC was discovered by the device only the Community App would be notified as this beacon falls outside of Business X's monitored region.

So in iOS at least each app will monitor beacons independently and if you have a single iBeacon that is being monitoried by multiple apps, all of these apps will be notified and then you would need your own logic to handle the events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this on iOS, but there are to things you must work around:

1. iBeacon detections always get sent to all iOS apps that are looking for them.  There is no built-in concept of priority or handling the events before other applications have a chance.
2. Applications are generally "sandboxed" to keep them from sharing data, although there are a few ways around this.

Because of (1), all apps are going to get the iBeacon notifications.  But you can program the community app to ignore events if it can be told by those other apps that they will handle or have handled events for one or more iBeacons.  Two ways to handle this notification within the confines of (2) is to use either a web service or a custom URL scheme to exchange data.  The second one might be the simplest for your case.

The way it would work is like this:

1. Business X App starts up, and starts monitoring for iBeacons with UUID 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6
2. Business X App makes a call to the custom URL scheme of communityIBeaconApp://start-ignoring?uuid=2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6&app=BusinessX
3. The community iBeacon App receives the custom URL call from (2) and knows it should now ignore all iBeacons with UUID 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6, because Business X app will handle them.
4. When the Business X App stops monitoring these iBeacons, it should make another call to communityIBeaconApp://stop-ignoring?uuid=2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6&app=BusinessX
5. The community iBeacon App receives the custom URL call from (3) and stops ignoring these iBeacons

You can read a tutorial about building custom URL schemes on iOS [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).